# How to get average of DATETIME column in MySQL while grouping by some other column

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am creating and filling a MySQL table with the following Queries:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';

CREATE TABLE timestamp_n_datetime (
    id INT,
    time DATETIME,
    avg_time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO timestamp_n_datetime(id,time,avg_time)
VALUES("1","2023-01-03 10:12:13", NULL),
("1", "2023-02-04 11:13:14", NULL),
("2", "2023-03-02 09:14:10", NULL),
("2", "2023-04-02 05:15:50", NULL),
("1", "2023-06-10 02:04:10", NULL);
```

I want to fill the 'avg_time' column with the average of 'time' column grouped by the id. For example the first row has 'id' = 1 so the 'avg_time' column should take the average of first, second and fifth row since their 'id' is also 1.

How could I approach this question?

Edit: For clarification I want all the DATETIME columns to be converted to miliseconds, adding all of them up and then dividing by the number added. For example For id=2 converting them to miliseconds adding them up and then dividing by 2 (because there are two rows with 'id' = 2) gives the average of March 17, 2023 5:45:00 PM. I want to get an average this way.

Comment: What do you expect the average time to be? What is an "average" time? Are you after a duration?

Comment: For example if the date's are '2023-02-04 11:10:10', '2023-02-04 11:10:20' I would expect the average to be '2023-02-04 11:10:15'. Of course this is on a scale of seconds but I want to get the average of dates like this. If maybe converting every DATETIME object to seconds than getting the average and then converting them back to DATETIME is possible that would work for me.

Comment: Please add the expected result as table in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using This `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` to convert to seconds, then `FROM_UNIXTIME` to get it back to datetime format, this is how you can get the average :

```
    select id, FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`)))
    from timestamp_n_datetime
    group by id;
```

This is how to fill the average :

```
update timestamp_n_datetime  td
inner join (
    select id, FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`))) as average
    from timestamp_n_datetime
    group by id
) as s on s.id = td.id
set avg_time = s.average;
```

Comment: Thank you! But the second part doesn't seem to update the table. Is there a problem with the code?

Comment: That's right, I have fixed it, Can you try it now